# Pending transaction shows as confirmed on blockchain explorer

Tags: multibit, multibit-hd

I'm using a MultiBit wallet (version 0.5.1) and a transfer from Coinbase to the wallet has been showing up as unconfirmed since March 18th (16 days).

Checking the transaction on the ledger, however, shows that it's been confirmed and completed. I've restarted the wallet, my computer, clicked "repair" and still nothing.

How can I go about attempting to get my transaction finalized?

Comment: Multibit is very old, and been abandoned by its original creator, and later abandoned by the company that acquired it (in 2017). You should probably migrate to something else: https://multibit.org/blog/2017/07/26/multibit-shutdown.html

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go about attempting to get my transaction finalized?

It seems the transaction *is* finalised. Its just that your wallet doesn't know about it.

> Checking the transaction on the ledger, however, shows that it's been confirmed and completed.

I assume this means you have checked the Transaction-ID against several different  Blockchain explorers and they all show the Transaction as having more than six confirmations.

In this case you need to do as Pieter Wuille suggested. Create a new wallet, using different software. Either import the private-key or sweep the private-key into the new wallet. There are important implications of these two approaches. People mostly recommend sweeping as safer for most folk.

Before it can show the correct balance, the new wallet may need to synchronise with the network (depending on whether you choose a full-node or lightweight wallet), if so this may take from a few days to a week or more.

Comment: So I went ahead and followd the instructions (standard wallet, enter seed, select BIP39 seed, select legacy since the previous address began with a '1'), however the new wallet opens with a balance of 0 btc. Wondering if this is a sign something went wrong or if this is the process that takes a few days/week+ (I don't see an indication that it's syncing w/the network)?